# Dockerfile build Laravel Telescope trying to connect to Redis service yet to "up"

Tags: php, laravel, docker, redis, docker-compose

My project is defined in a docker-compose file, but I'm not too familiar with docker-compose definitions.

When I try to `docker-compose up -d` in a fresh setup, the following error occurred during the build of a docker image.

This is after `composer install`, under `post-autoload-dump`. Laravel tries to auto discover packages (`php artisan package:discover`).

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   RedisException  : php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

  at [internal]:0
    1|

  Exception trace:

  1   ErrorException::("Redis::connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known")
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:126

  2   Redis::connect("my_redis", "6379")
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:126

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
ERROR: Service 'my_app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c composer global require hirak/prestissimo && composer install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The reason it cannot connect to `my_redis:6379` is because `my_redis` is another service in the same `docker-compose.yml` file. So I assume the domain is not ready yet, since docker-compose wants to first build my images before hosting containers.

---

**EDIT** I just found this GitHub issue linking to my problem: https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/620. It seems that the problem is related to Telescope trying to use the Cache driver. The difference is I'm not using Docker just for CI/CD, but for my local development.

---

**How can I resolve this problem? Is there a way to force Redis container to up first before building `my_app`? Or is there a Laravel way to prevent any domain discovery? Or is there a way to specify the building of an image depends on another service to be available?**

---

If you want to see my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.6'
services:

  # Redis Service
  my_redis:
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
    container_name: my_redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - redisdata:/data
    networks:
      - app-network

  # Postgres Service
  my_db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    container_name: my_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: my
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: postgres
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql
      - ./postgres/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - app-network

  # PHP Service
  my_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: my/php
    container_name: my_app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: my_app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - /tmp:/tmp #For CS Fixer
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
      - fsdata:/my
    networks:
      - app-network

  # Nginx Service
  my_webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: my_webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

# Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

# Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
  redisdata:
    driver: local
  fsdata:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 1):

I currently mitigated this by adding `--no-scripts` to Dockerfile and added a `start.sh`. Since it is Laravel's package discovery script that binds to `post-autoload-dump` that wants to access Redis.

Dockerfile excerpt

```
#...
# Change current user to www
USER www

# Install packages
RUN composer global require hirak/prestissimo && composer install --no-scripts

RUN chmod +x /var/www/scripts/start.sh

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["/var/www/scripts/start.sh"]
```

start.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
composer dumpautoload
php-fpm
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to force a service to wait another service in docker compose [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends-on), but it only wait until the container is up not the service, and to fix that you have to customize redis image by using `command` to execute a bash script that check for redis container and redis daemon availability check [startup-order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've resolve this yourself by now but for anyone else coming across this question later, there are two solutions I have found:

#### 1. Ensure Redis is up and running before your App

In your `redis` service in `docker-compose.yml` add this...

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
```

...then in your `my_app` service in `docker-compose.yml` add...

```
depends_on:
  redis:
    condition: service_healthy
```

#### 2. Use separate docker compose setups for local development and CI/CD pipelines

Even better in my opinion is to create a new `docker-compose.test.yml` In here you can omit the `redis` service entirely and just use the `CACHE_DRIVER=array`. You could set this either directly in your the environment property of your `my_app` service or create a `.env.testing`. (make sure to set `APP_ENV=testing` too).

I like this approach because as your application grows there may be more and more packages which you want to enable/disable or configure differently in your testing environment and using `.env.testing` in conjunction with a `docker-compose.testing.yml` is a great way to manage that.